# How can I add multiple routes in Web.Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have created a asp.net web.api. I have one controller named Books which has 2 methods that look like this..

```
public IHttpActionResult Read(string pass, string Id)

public IHttpActionResult Update(string pass, string Id)
```

How do I add routes for both methods in my `webApiConfig` file?

Right now I only have this that work on Read method.

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{pass}/{Id}",
            defaults: new { transationId = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This one I can access like this..
Api/Books/xxxxpasscodexxx/1

How would the route for the update method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Attribute

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Read(string pass,int id)

[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Update(string pass,int id)
```

Add the routing in webapiconfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{pass}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Note:** this must be above the existing route, otherwise it will take precedence.

Comment: Thanks @sakhib, it worked but I had to remove the default route otherwise only the Update method worked

Answer (score 1):

you can use the current default route for update also.web api will provide [FromUri] attribute for reading action parameters from URI of Httprequestmessage  .

```
[HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Update([FromUri]string pass, [FromUri]string Id)
    {

        //do your stuff here and return
    }
```

your request should be Api/Books?password=xxxx&string=abc

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#attribute-routing). You can mark your Controller as APIController, specify the general route and then define the http verb and method path with the Route parameter. This will overwrite your Routes.MapHttpRoute definition.

Answer (score 0):

Change your routing to

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{pass}/{Id}",
        defaults: new { transationId = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```